# Shift landscape environment to the previous page

Tags: landscape, afterpage

A typical solution while using the `landscape` environment provided by the `pdflscape` package is to wrap the `landscape` into an `\afterpage{}` environment to prevent clearing the page between the part to be rotated and the preceding text. In this way, the following text flushes before the landscape-oriented page until the landscape page comes.

Is there any equivalent to `\afterpage{}` that positions the landscape page *before* the page in which it is called instead of *after* it?
More often than not, figures, tables, diagrams and the like are best inserted in a textflow before they are described textually, so this solution would come in handy in those situations.

I have not included any MWE as I am not referring to any specific problem I have experienced.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

No. This isn't possible (without changing the whole output routine). TeX works token-by-token, paragraph-by-paragraph, page-by-page. When the macro on page *n* is read, page *n-1* is done and dusted. (This isn't quite true - LaTeX does peek a little ahead, but only a little and nothing like a whole page.)

If you are happy to put the picture on *this* page and move everything else from this page to the *next* page, rather than putting the picture on the *previous* page, then you can, as David says, insert a page into the output to achieve this.

Here's a very crude version as proof-of-concept:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,everypage,kantlipsum,rotating,calc}
\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{.5\paperwidth-.5\textwidth-1in-\parindent}
\newlength\myotherlength
\setlength\myotherlength{.5\paperheight-.5\textheight-1in}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-4]% this text runs from page 1 to page 2, but ends up on page 1 and page 3
\shipout\vbox{% this code is on page 2 and ends up on page 2
  \refstepcounter{page}%
  \vskip\myotherlength
  \hskip\mylength
  \includegraphics[width=\textheight,height=\textwidth,keepaspectratio,angle=90]{example-image-a}%
}%
\kant[5-7]% this ends up on page 3 and later
\end{document}
```

[image: inserted page]

Comment: it wouldn't be that hard to insert a page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No. But that wouldn't put it on the *previous* page. It would put it on *this* page and move the rest of the stuff from this page to the *next* page. I thought that was the question.

Comment: since a landscape page is a complete page insert it comes to the same thing. It just depends how you define "this page" you can not change the text in the previous page for the reasons you give above but you could output a  page before rather than after the current page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, nothing ends up on the previous page, was my point. But, yes, it isn't clear that is really wanted in this case. Maybe ....

Comment: As there seem to be no straightforward solutions, only workarounds, wouldn'it be more simple to move the `\afterpage{...}` a few paragraphs up so that it actually ends up on the desired page?

Comment: @poxx Well, yes, that would be simpler, obviously. But you asked for a way not to have to do that. At least, so I assumed.

Comment: Also, your proposed solution doesn't really change the page orientation, resulting in the reader having to bend their head to watch the image...

Comment: @poxx For electronic, you mean? Yes, that's very true. I just added this because I was curious after David said it could be done this way, but I'm pretty clueless at manipulating this kind of thing, so it really is only a very rough proof-of-concept.